# How can I apply if command on five select option values to get three out put?

Tags: html, if-statement, select, command, calculation

I hope that you have a good day, I am making a diet calculator that allows you to input your daily calories and choose between 5 diets (each diet has an amount of protein,carb and fats per day) and I want the calculator to multiply the amount of calories by the selected diet 3 fractions and get the 3 results of the amounts you should consume per day of the three elements, but the code does not work and I can not apply the if command to the variables and I do not know what to do as I am new to coding, I hope you help me and you will know what the calculator is about when you read the code, Have a good day!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title </title>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">


</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="card">
<div class="card-header text-center" dir="rtl"> اصنع نظامك الغذائي بنفسك </div>
<div class="card-body">
<form class="w-50 m-auto"> 
<div class="form-group">
<label>: ادخل سعراتك الحرارية اليومية هنا </label>
<input type="number" placeholder="بلاش تحط سكر, كفاية انت" class="form-control"  id="calorie" required>



<div class="form-group">

<select id="getdeit" class="form-control"dir="rtl" > 
<option> اختر نظامك الغذائي المناسب لهدفك</option>
<option value="lose"> خسارة دهون - 40% بروتين - 40% كارب - 20% دهون </option>
<option value="bulk"> تضخيم - 30% بروتين - 60% كارب - 10% دهون </option>
<option value="shred"> تنشيف - 60% بروتين - 30% كارب - 10% دهون </option>
<option value="eshred"> تنشيف حاد - 70% بروتين - 20% كارب - 10% دهون </option>
<option value="kito"> كيتو دايت - 20% بروتين - 5% كارب - 75% دهون </option>
</select>

</div>


</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label>: البروتين </label>
<output type="number" placeholder="000" class="form-control"  id="newprotein" readonly>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label>:الكاربوهيدرات</label>
<output type="number" placeholder="000" class="form-control"  id="newcarb" readonly>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label>: الدهون</label>
<output type="number" placeholder="000" class="form-control"  id="newfat" readonly>
</div>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" onclick=" getprotein()">
 احصل علي نظامك الغذائي الآن
</button>
<div>
</div>

</form>
</div>
<div class="card-footer text-center"> Test </div>

</div>
</div>


<script>
function protein(){
var calorie = document.getElementById('calorie').value;
var lose = document.getElementById('lose').value=;
var bulk = document.getElementById('bulk').value=;
var shred = document.getElementById('shred').value;
var eshred = document.getElementById('eshred').value;
var kito = document.getElementById('kito').value;

if id ="lose"{
var newprotein = (calorie*0.4)/4
var newcarb = (calorie*0.4)/4
var newfat = (calorie*0.2)/9
}
if id ="bulk"{
var newprotein = (calorie*0.3)/4
var newcarb = (calorie*0.6)/4
var newfat = (calorie*0.1)/9
}
if id ="shred"{
var newprotein = (calorie*0.6)/4
var newcarb = (calorie*0.3)/4
var newfat = (calorie*0.1)/9
}
if id ="eshred"{
var newprotein = (calorie*0.7)/4
var newcarb = (calorie*0.2)/4
var newfat = (calorie*0.1)/9
}
if id ="kito"{
var newprotein = (calorie*0.2)/4
var newcarb = (calorie*0.05)/4
var newfat = (calorie*0.75)/9
}
document.getElementById('protein').value = newprotein;
document.getElementById('carb').value = newcarb;
document.getElementById('fat').value = newfat;

}
</script>







<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your `if` syntax is wrong.

Comment: could you fix it please because I can not do it properly

Answer (score 0):

Your if-statement is wrong. The if-statement you provided assigns the variable `id` the value `lose`

More information about [if-statements](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_variables.asp) and [variable assignment](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp)

To fix your issue

```
id ="lose"
```

should be

```
id === "lose"
```